# Spring JPA Repository merge instead of save

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Could you help me with JPA Repository? During update request and using POST method - I need to save only fields that I sent into my POST body. But if I didn't write it into body JPA Repository set is as null (DB MySQL, default null). Please look the picture. 
[image]

If I don't send in bode airport code it becaming null after update. But it was "UAAA". How do I manage it? Thanks in advice!

Model class cut:

```
@Entity 
@SelectBeforeUpdate 
@DynamicUpdate 
@Table(name = "airports") 
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}) 
public class Airports {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private long id;
     private String airport; 
     private String code;
```

Controller class cut:

```
@RestController
public class AirportsController {
    private AirportsRepository repository;


    public AirportsController(AirportsRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "airports/update")
    public ResponseEntity updateAirportById(@RequestBody Airports airports) {
        Airports foundedById = repository.findOne(airports.getId());
        foundedById.setAirport(airports.getAirport());
        foundedById.setCode(airports.getCode());
        repository.save(foundedById);

        return new ResponseEntity(foundedById, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you set values in controller updateAirportById method even if they are null.
If you didn't pass values of "code" and "airport" in the body the method getAirports return null and set it to foundedById and then it updates it. Simple if condition should solve this problem

```
if(airports.getAirport() != null) 
  foundedById.setAirport(airports.getAirport());
```

And the same for "code"

Comment: calling `save()` will persist null as defaultvalue on the column `code` anyway. There is a preload or other query needed to just update given fields. That´s what it is about.

Comment: It won't because he take record from database in first line. So if he didn't update value with null it will have it's own value

Comment: It's really working! Thank you Rafał Sokalski! Have a nice day bro!!